# File encoding VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, encoding

So I opened python file from PyCharm project with VS Code and got unexpected error with encoding. There are a row in code

```
matches = re.finditer(r'["«»][А-Я][а-я]+["«»]', preprocessed_text)
```

When trying to run it from terminal in VS Code I get error

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file depers.py on line 109,
> but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for
> details

But everything works like a charm in PyCharm and from system terminal. Then I tried to add encoding at the top of the file

> # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

After that I received

> File "depers.py", line 2, in
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd ImportError:
> ```
>
> No module named pandas

So the editor forgot how letters look like. Also tried vscode auto-detecting of encoding. Don't seem to be useful.

It seems like my obvious mistake. Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Do you have 2 separate interpreters on 2 different IDE's

Comment: I use same virtual environment for all cases

Answer (score 0):

Yep, my bad. The thing is I didn't activate virtual environment in VS Code terminal. After using command

> source bin/activate

in my environment directory code executed well.

This never happened in PyCharm because it activates virtual environment automatically.

The other thing that I installed Run Code plugin to VS Code and it has some issues with encoding.